# Key "getPageTitle" for array with keys "0" does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm getting this error

> Key "getPageTitle" for array with keys "0" does not exist in
>   DprocMainBundle:Dproc:single.html.twig at line 2

line 2 : `{{ page.getPageTitle }}`

My entity file

```
<?php
namespace Dproc\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @IgnoreAnnotation("fn")
 *
 */
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="pages")
 */
class Pages
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $Id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="page_title", type="text")
    */
    protected $pageTitle;

    /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="page_content", type="text")
 */
    protected $pageContent;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="page_category", type="text")
    */
    protected $pageCategory;

    /**
     * Get Id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }

    /**
     * Set page_title
     *
     * @param string $pageTitle
     * @return Pages
     */
    public function setPageTitle($pageTitle)
    {
        $this->pageTitle = $pageTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page_title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageTitle()
    {
        return $this->pageTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set page_content
     *
     * @param string $pageContent
     * @return Pages
     */
    public function setPageContent($pageContent)
    {
        $this->pageContent = $pageContent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page_content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageContent()
    {
        return $this->pageContent;
    }

    /**
     * Set page_category
     *
     * @param string $pageCategory
     * @return Pages
     */
    public function setPageCategory($pageCategory)
    {
        $this->pageCategory = $pageCategory;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get page_category
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPageCategory()
    {
        return $this->pageCategory;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function IndexAction($slug)
    {
        $page = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('DprocMainBundle:Pages')
           ->findByPageTitle($slug);

        if (!$page) {
           throw $this->createNotFoundException('No product found for slug '.$slug);
        }
        //print_r($page);
        return $this->render('DprocMainBundle:Dproc:single.html.twig',array('page' => $page));
    }
```

What i'm doing wrong, how shoud i call my getter method getPageTitle?

Thanks

Comment: `{{ page.PageTitle }}`

Comment: @cheesemacfly I think that now it is `{{ page.page_title }}`

Answer (score 15):

the error is stemming from your doctrine call. If you change

```
$page = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('DprocMainBundle:Pages')
       ->findByPageTitle($slug);
```

to:

```
$page = $this->getDoctrine()
       ->getRepository('DprocMainBundle:Pages')
       ->findOneByPageTitle($slug);
```

You should be all set. The problem was that 'page' was an array of pages (probably an array with only a single page, but an array nonetheless). By changing the method to findOneByX you are ensuring that Doctrine will return a single object, not an array of objects. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your result is an array because `findByPageTitle($slug)` will return an array of all matches, even if there is only one. Instead do `findOneBy(array('pageTitle'=>$slug))` and you will get a single result. It's likely with your current setup that `{{ page.0.getPageTitle }}` would work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to use the getter function then you need to do:

```
{{page.getPageTitle()}}
```

Notice the parenthesis. If you want twig to automagically use the getter function you can do

```
{{page.pageTitle}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `{{page.pageTitle|default('')}}`? It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: `getResult()` returns an array of objects, even if there is only one. If you are expecting that this query would return only one object use `getOneOrNullResult()`.